# What is ConnectionError Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2]?

Tags: pi-3, networking, python-3

I am running a 6 script and they are running at different timings using systemd service and timer. Each script access the same url at least once. When I check the log file of some scripts, they are showing an error like following

```
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.xxxxxxxx.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sensorConfig (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x75d165b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))",),)
```

I replaced the site name with xxxxxxxx since it is confidential. Actually, I was thinking it was due to the internet failure but it was not. Because I can access the site using the browser without problem and also I can ping to the same site without problem.

I am actually sending POST requests using the python3.6 package "requests.post".

I have searched the internet but no one gives a solution.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: does the site accept POST requests?

Comment: Yes the scripts don't have problem always. only sometimes

Comment: well, you say `I was thinking it was due to the internet failure but it was not. Because I can access the site using the browser` ... but unless you try to access the site with a browser at EXACTLY the same time as when a script fails, how can you rule out internet failure?

Comment: One more thing, I was controlling the raspberry pi using anydesk remote access. Unless the internet is not available, I can't control it. when run the script manually, i got the error.

Comment: Are you sure the remote site can handle the load - with the service not being available I feel its the host end more than the Pi?  Any command accessing services outside the current Pi program should be built around a try / except block in Python https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp to stop your program dying.

Comment: I found some blogs saying that request with session will solve this issue. Is there a chance for that?

Comment: @Andrew I ran two scripts in two different api and observed this same error in rpi 1 but at the same rpi2 was able to contact the host. Hence host is not the problem